# What is the maximum frequency to use diodes for distortion?

Tags: rf, diodes, high-frequency, distortion

What is the maximum frequency to use rectifier, Schottky or Zener diodes for cut off sin wave to square wave?

Comment: Depends on the diode. What does the datasheet say about trr or junction capacitance?

Comment: Depending on the device, up to THz. You need to know the capacitance, carrier lifetime, transit time, etc. See https://cdn.macom.com/applicationnotes/AG312.pdf

Comment: In theory no idea depends on the limits of physical chemistry.  In practice which diode? Reverse recovery time, junction capacitance and a lot of other factors play a role in determining this.  If you have a specific diode in mind which?  Add a link to the data sheet in the question and we may be able to provide more help.

Comment: 0 Hz. You cannot make a square wave by cutting off a sine wave. But you can _approximate_ a square wave, and then the maximum frequency depends on how closely you need to approximate a true square wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP used to sell its 5082_2935 schottky (and others) with 100 picosecond time constants

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of diode used, for example;

- The frequency rating of the diode
- The material the diode is made of
- the type of diode you want to use

---

- rectifier diodes= low freq
- shottky diodes= medium freq
- RF diodes = high freq